# [firedac][phys][sqlite] error database table when recompiling aplication

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, c++builder, firedac

I'm get an error `[firedac][phys][sqlite] error database table tablename` when trying to delete table rows or post to a table. 
This doesn't happen when i delete the app from android(debugging device) and run it for the first time(as long as the app is open i can do deletes and posts). 
But when i close the app and try to run it again it gives an error on posts or deletes(`[firedac][phys][sqlite] error database table tablename`).

I tyed closing all `FDQuery`'s and `FDConnection`(i have one connection) then calling `DisposeOf()` on all of them (didn't work).
`FDConnection`'s `LockingMode` is set to normal.
I also tryed `FDConnection->ReleaseClients(rmOffline)` (didn't work).
All queryes have the same transaction.

Is it a Transaction problem?
How to debug this?

Comment: debud or debug ;)

Comment: I'm quite doubtful such exception can ever be raised.

Comment: I managed to raise it somehow